# Formatting with Charts

Tags: vba, excel

I have a sheet and I am generating the Chart from a table.

I would like to generate 2 charts. One chart with absolute numbers and other chart for the same data with Percentage.

Right now, for this, I am using two code, just by adding a line for generating the chart with Y.axis in percentage.

I would like to define column where my chart will start (for eg: chart1 from G7) and chart2 from G15. (I don't have this in my code)

I also, would like to define the length , height and width for my chart.(I don't have this in my code)

It would be great if you can help me add this requirement and do it In a single program.

```
Sub chartstatus()

Dim rng As Range
Dim cht As Object

Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("A2:E53")

Set sh = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart
sh.Select
Set cht = ActiveChart
With cht
    .SetSourceData Source:=rng
    .ChartType = xlColumnClustered
    cht.Axes(xlSecondary).TickLabels.NumberFormat = "0.0%"
End With

cht.SeriesCollection(1).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 255) '<~~ Red
cht.SeriesCollection(2).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
cht.SeriesCollection(3).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 255, 0)
cht.HasTitle = True
cht.ChartTitle.Text = "Result 2017"

End Sub
```

I use the same code, deleting the line to generate the second chart

```
cht.Axes(xlSecondary).TickLabels.NumberFormat = "0.0%"
```

Comment: can you show your sheet data?.  and you result chart image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easier way if to use the `ChartObject` to create and define the chart, and then modify all it's properties (such as position and dimension).

The code below will create the first chart, place it in Cell "G7", and I modifed it's dimensions to show you the properties you need to modify.

You can add another one for the second chart (with an easy copy>>paste).

***Code***

```
Option Explicit

Sub chartstatus()

Dim Rng As Range
Dim ChtObj As ChartObject

Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("A2:E53")

' use ChartObject instead of shape
Set ChtObj = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(100, 100, 500, 500) '<-- default dimension and location >> can modify later
With ChtObj
    .Chart.ChartType = xlColumnClustered
    .Chart.SetSourceData Rng

    With .Chart
        .Axes(xlSecondary).TickLabels.NumberFormat = "0.0%"

        .SeriesCollection(1).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 255) '<~~ Red
        .SeriesCollection(2).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        .SeriesCollection(3).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 255, 0)
        .HasTitle = True
        .ChartTitle.Text = "Result 2017"
    End With

    ' set position of the chart to Cell G7
    .Top = Range("G7").Top
    .Left = Range("G7").Left

    ' change the dimensions of the chart
    With .Chart.ChartArea
        .Width = 1060
        .Height = 420
    End With
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I can copy paste, but I don't need my axis in percentage for the second chart

Comment: @Jenny were you able to get my code run also on your second chart ?

Comment: @Jenny you're welocme :) now comes your part as a "good citizen" of **SO** where you mark it as "ANSWER"

Comment: Shai Rado I did it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150284/discussion-between-jenny-and-shai-rado).

Answer (score 0):

For  changing  the chart location  :

[vba to add a shape at a specific cell location in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16038893/vba-to-add-a-shape-at-a-specific-cell-location-in-excel)

For  chart size:

sh.Width =100
sh.Height =100